# How much thumbnails can I store until I run out of memory?

Tags: android, memory-management, thumbnails

For my app, I'm currently reading through ALL the image (JPEG) files stored on the phone and saving their ID, and thumbnails (NOT the original Bitmap) onto a HashMap.

Code:

```
final String[] PROJECTION =
                new String[] {MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};

Cursor pictureCursor = getContentResolver().query(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                PROJECTION, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

HashMap<Integer,Bitmap> thumbnails = new HashMap<Integer,Bitmap>();

int id;
int id_index = pictureCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

int THUMBNAIL_TYPE = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND;
ContentResolver content_resolver = context.getContentResolver();

while (pictureCursor.moveToNext()) {

    id = pictureCursor.getInt(id_index);
    Bitmap thumbnail = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(content_resolver, id, THUMBNAIL_TYPE, null);
    thumbnails.put(id, thumbnail);
}
```

I currently have 200 images on my phone, and it works fine now. But I'm worried that at certain point, the app will run out of memory and crash.

Is running out of memory something I need to take into consideration? Or are thumbnails small enough that practically speaking, the app won't run out of memory?

*EDIT*
If I should worry about running out of memory, what's the best way if I want something like Android's native gallery app, which doesn't seem to have a "load more images" button but rather an endless stream of images?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MICRO_KIND thumbnails are not very big, and you will very likely be fine.  But if you are putting your app out there, you will absolutely find people with memory problems.  It will be due to either an insane number of photos, a mediocre device, or some combination of the two.

You can calculate the memory use of your thumbnails.  It shouldn't be too hard to create one or two thumbnails, and find out how big they are.  Then you can calculate available heap (Native heap on pre 3.0, Dalvik heap after 3.0) and get an idea of how many you can make.

You can get a count of the items in your cursor at this point in your code:

Cursor pictureCursor = getContentResolver().query(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
                PROJECTION, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
int numberOfImages = pictureCursor.getCount() 
HashMap thumbnails = new HashMap();

and then know if you have plenty of room or not.  If you are limited in space, you will need to make a design decision--either warn the user that its not going to work, or only look at the first "x" images, then free those up and load another set at the users request.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on heap size and how memory intensive your app is.

I suggest you have a look at the video in the link

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk.

If you run into memory leaks you can use MAT Analyzer to find and fix the problem.

You need to reduce memory usage and if heap sizes grows and your app requires  space in heap, the gc kicks in to free memory. But if there is not enough space you are likely to run into memory leaks.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html